# c# Multiple Independent Filters on Lambda Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I've been working on this for hours today and feel like there is an easy way to do this but I am unable to make it work by anything but brute force.

I have an entity in my application that serves as a Mapping between two objects, based on 5 filters. The goal is to find the record with the most specific match to the filters.

Right now, I am manually brute forcing 2^5 queries to get the most specific row, but feel like there has to be a much easier way to do this.

The only gotcha here is that there may be no match in the database for a specific filter (or all), in which case I want to select the NULL record.

Below I have an excerpt of my embarrassing brute force query -- I first want to try and match on all 5 filters, then on permutations of 4 matching, then 3, then 2, then 1, and finally all Nulls.

```
incList.FirstOrDefault(x =>
                x.Filter1 == filter1Parameter && x.Filter2 == filter2Parameter && x.Filter3 == filter3Parameter && x.Filter4 == filter4Parameter && x.Filter5 == filter5Parameter
                || x.Filter1 == null && x.Filter2 == filter2Parameter && x.Filter3 == filter3Parameter && x.Filter4 == filter4Parameter && x.Filter5 == filter5Parameter
                || x.Filter1 == filter1Parameter && x.Filter2 == null && x.Filter3 == filter3Parameter && x.Filter4 == filter4Parameter && x.Filter5 == filter5Parameter
                || x.Filter1 == filter1Parameter && x.Filter2 == filter2Parameter && x.Filter3 == null && x.Filter4 == filter4Parameter && x.Filter5 == filter5Parameter
                || x.Filter1 == filter1Parameter && x.Filter2 == filter2Parameter && x.Filter3 == filter3Parameter && x.Filter4 == null && x.Filter5 == filter5Parameter
                || x.Filter1 == filter1Parameter && x.Filter2 == filter2Parameter && x.Filter3 == filter3Parameter && x.Filter4 == filter4Parameter && x.Filter5 == null
```

I originally thought I could have a simple statement that would independently grab the value if present, and grab null if not

```
                   incList.FirstOrDefault(x => (x.Filter1 == filter1Parameter || x.Filter1 == null) &&
                                    (x.Filter2 == filter2Parameter || x.Filter2 == null) &&
                                    (x.Filter3 == filter3Parameter || x.Filter3 == null) &&
                                    (x.Filter4 == filter4Parameter || x.Filter4 == null) &&
                                    (x.Filter5 == filter5Parameter || x.Filter5 == null));
```

But that did not work.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "But that did not work" ? Also, the example would be much easier to read with two or three filters instead of five.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still trying to understand the full extent of the requirement.

However, have you explored abstracting this Func or Func(s) in a separate class. This separate class or classes would operate like a Strategy. Only in charge of what filters a collection based on a certain predicate.

If that does not seem like a good route, what about looking into writing your own implementation IEqualityComparer. This will allow you determine what makes these objects equal.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce something like a "fitness function" and then select item with max fit value

```
var bestMatch = incList.Select(x => new
{
    item = x,
    fit = 
        (x.Filter1 == null 
            ? 1 
            : (x.Filter1 == filter1Parameter ? 2 : 0)) *
        (x.Filter2 == null 
            ? 1 
            : (x.Filter2 == filter2Parameter ? 2 : 0)) // and so on
})
.OrderByDescending(x => x.fit)
.FirstOrDefault(x => x.fit > 0)?.item;
```